# Why does my XML data get all mixed up?

Tags: php, xml

i have a problem with getting content from a XML into a mysql database.
This is the code:

```
 $objDOM = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$objDOM->load("something.xml"); $IAutnr = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("Data");
```

Now, in a for loop:

```
for($i=$t;$i<=$max;$i++) { 

$some= $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("some");
$something = $some->item($i)->nodeValue;
$some2 = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("some2");
$something2  = $some2->item($i)->nodeValue;

Now put $something and $something2 into the database
}
```

Now, what happens is, that everything works perfectly fine until one of the Elements (some,some2...) does not exist within the tag "Data". So what he does, is taking the element from the next "Data"-tag and this mixes all my data, so I have data in my database, that actually doesnt belong there. And so I have an all mixed up database.
I allready tried for several hours to change the XML manually by putting the missing tags inside, but with thousands of data records, it is not possible.
So I need to add something into my code, that will have the effect, that if the tag doesnt exist, just leave it and dont take the tag from the next "Data"-Tag.
I actually dont even understand why he is doing that, why is he just jumping into the next "Data"-tag?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This is an example: `<Data><nr>123</nr><znr>12345</znr><status>fd</status>
<title>Some title</TITEL>
<titlenr>76</titlenr></Data>`

Comment: @phpheini So where are your `<some>` and `<some2>` elements? Also, try editing your answer to post more information.

Comment: this was just an example, imagine being <nr> = <some> and <znr> = <some2>

Comment: @phpheini Sorry, I meant edit your "question", not "answer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only guessing here about the content of your XML structure, but I imagine it looks something like

```
...
<Data>
    <some>a</some>
    <some2>b</some2>
</Data>
<Data>
    <some>c</some>
    <some2>d</some2>
</Data>
...
```

If this is the case, you should be looping over the collection of `Data` elements in `$IAutnr`, eg

```
for($i = 0, $limit = min($IAutnr->length, $max); $i < $limit; $i++) {
    $data = $IAutnr->item($i);
    $some = $data->getElementsByTagName('some');
    $something = $some->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $some2 = $data->getElementsByTagName('some2');
    $something2 = $some2->item(0)->nodeValue;

    // insert
}
```

---

Unless you need some of the more advanced features of the DOM library, I'd recommend using SimpleXML.

Comment: The problem is, I dont want to use foreach since I need to have a $max, where the loop should stop

Comment: hm, this is weird. Now he is inputting the first row into the database and after the first one the rest is only 0 for every column.

By the way: Did you forget to put $i instead of 0 at `$some2->item(0)->nodeValue;` or was it on purpose?

Comment: @phpheini No, the `0` means the first node from the `DOMNodeList` returned by `getElementsByTagName()`. You still haven't clarified your XML structure so I'm only guessing there's only one each of the "some" and "some2" elements in each `<Data>` node

Comment: Yes thats right. Only one some and one some2 in each <Data>. The structure is like you wrote in your post.

Answer (score 0):

It does that because you're asking it to extract elements with tag name "some" and "some2" from the entire XML structure, so that's what it does -- it doesn't only look into the branch you intend it to, because you never tell it to do that. One way to fix it is to look at $some->items($i)->parentNode (and maybe to that node's parent, and so on) in order to properly identify the parent $something and $something2 belong to. Of course, there's no guarantee that $something and $something2 belong to the same parent, unless your XML is somehow guaranteed to present either none or both within the same branch. I know the explanation's a bit hairy, but that's the best way I could put it into words.

Comment: But doesnt he know that $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("Data"); And then for every $objDOM get <some> and <some2>
If the script would take any <some> in the XML, then there wouldnt be a point of defining where to take them from (from withing <Data></Data>)!

Comment: @phpheini `$objDOM` is the entire document. If you wanted to limit the `<some*>` context to each `<Data>` element, you need to perform your search operations on those nodes (which you have already fetched into `$IAutnr`)

Comment: $objDOM is the entire document, but $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("Data"); chooses the area between <Data> and </Data>, doesnt it?

Comment: @phpheini Yes, and it assigns that `DOMNodeList` to `$IAutnr`, not `$objDOM`